# Generating numbers in log-normal distribution not giving right parameters in return?

Tags: python, numpy, random

So I am trying to implement a function to generate random number following log-normal distribution myself. (Despite I am testing it in numpy, I need it for somewhere else where out of the box function is unavailable).

Using Box-Muller transform to generate Normally distributed random number and taking exponential of it (suggested in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/481638/generating-random-numbers-that-are-log-normally-distributed)), and referring to [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) I come up with this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()

def f():
    mean = 100
    sigma = 50

    u = np.log((mean * mean) / np.sqrt(mean * mean + sigma * sigma))
    d = np.log(1 + (sigma * sigma) / (mean * mean))

    u1 = 0
    while u1 <= 0.0000001:
        u1 = rng.random()
    u2 = rng.random()

    mag = d * np.sqrt(-2 * np.log(u1))
    z0 = mag * np.cos(2 * np.pi * u2) + u
    z1 = mag * np.sin(2 * np.pi * u2) + u

    return (np.exp(z0), np.exp(z1))

iteration = 100000

data = []
for i in range(0, iteration):
    x = f()
    data.append(x[0])
    data.append(x[1])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(data, bins=100) 

print('mean: ' + str(np.mean(data)))
print('median: ' + str(np.median(data)))
print('stdev: ' + str(np.std(data)))
```

However, the generated values does not have the right mean and stdev, even though the shape seems to be vaguely correct. Does I miss anything? Or is it just some floating point shenanigans?

[image: matplotlib histogram plot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So problem is getting log-normal with specific mean and stddev values. To do that you have to get log-normal distribution parameters **μ**, **σ** from mean and stddev (denoted **m** and **s**). THen you sample N(0,1) via Box-Muller. Then you make them N(**μ**, **σ**), simple linear transformation. And at last you take exp() of sampled values because log-normal could be seen as distribution for logarithms.

Code, Win 10 x64, Python 3.10

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = np.random.default_rng(135797537)

def squared(x: np.float64) -> np.float64:
    return x*x

def sample_normal_BM() -> tuple[np.float64, np.float64]:
    """Sample two normal RVs using Box-Muller method"""

    u = 1.0 - rng.random() # guaranteed (0...1]
    v = rng.random()

    r = np.sqrt(-2.0 * np.log(u))
    p = 2.0 * np.pi * v

    return r*np.cos(p), r*np.sin(p)

def calc_μσ(m: np.float64, s: np.float64) -> tuple[np.float64, np.float64]:
    """From desired mean and stddev calculate μ,σ for lognormal"""

    σ = np.sqrt(np.log((squared(s) + squared(m))/squared(m)))
    μ = np.log(m) - squared(σ)/2
    
    return μ, σ

def sample_lognormal(μ: np.float64, σ: np.float64) -> tuple[np.float64, np.float64]:
    n1, n2 = sample_normal_BM()
    
    n1 = σ*n1 + μ
    n2 = σ*n2 + μ
    
    return np.exp(n1), np.exp(n2)

m = 100.0 # desired mean
s = 50.0  # desired stddev

μ, σ = calc_μσ(m, s)

N = 100000

data = []
for i in range(0, N):
    ln1, ln2 = sample_lognormal(μ, σ)
    data.append(ln1)
    data.append(ln2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(data, bins=100) 

print('mean: ' + str(np.mean(data)))
print('median: ' + str(np.median(data)))
print('stdev: ' + str(np.std(data)))
```

Output should produce something like
[image]

and print out value which are quite close to desired

```
mean: 100.00006076705726
median: 89.3329385030017
stdev: 50.09847133246042
```