# Parameterizing a log normal distribution in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, distribution, montecarlo

I'm trying to run some monte carlo simulations in Sheets, and want the option of specifying a lognormal distribution. I want to parameterize this based on the mean and 25th percentile i.e. when I run 1,000 draws from this distribution, the mean should = 10 and the 25th percentile should = 8 (for example).

I feel this should be sufficient info to parameterize the two-parameter distribution, but I'm having trouble implementing it in practice. I know I need to transform these estimates to natural logarithms somehow, but am not sure exactly how.

Please could someone help me out? My current attempts are here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bwVhTS3nqQAehBrdLUczJSVAgVcd6TzJSwCYbmQy6dc/edit#gid=0. I'm trying to get the random draws in column F to have mean 10 and 25th percentile 8, but my current formula isn't quite right.

Sorry for the basic Q -- I've spent an hour banging my head on this and would really appreciate a guiding light...

I tried googling, reading formulae online, ChatGPT. I've tried experimenting with various ln transformations and am getting close to the right answer, but no cigar.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76883750/generating-numbers-in-log-normal-distribution-not-giving-right-parameters-in-ret/ would help? Though not about quantiles, but it derives log-normal from mean and stddev.

Answer (score 0):

Let me post an answer, but in Python - I don't know how to deal with Google Sheets. Hope it would be helpful.  Main gist here, as you properly noted, is to solve coupled non-linear equations, to get log-normal μ, σ distribution parameters from desired mean and quantile. I used fsolve() from SciPy, got parameters, use them to sample from log-normal some RVs, and then estimated mean and quantile from the sample

Code, Python 3.10 Windows 10 x64

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
from scipy.special import erfinv

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


SQRT_2 = np.sqrt(2.0)

def ff(variables):
    m   = 10.0 # desired mean
    q25 =  8.0 # desired quantile
    p   = 25.0/100.0 # quantile pct

    μ, σ = variables

    mean_eq  = np.exp(μ + σ*σ/2) - m # equation for mean
    quant_eq = np.exp(μ + SQRT_2*σ * erfinv(2*p - 1)) - q25 # equation for quantile function

    return [mean_eq, quant_eq]

μ, σ = opt.fsolve(ff, (5,1) ) # non-linear solver with equations and start point
print(μ, σ)

rng = np.random.default_rng(135797537)
data = rng.lognormal(μ, σ, 200000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(data, bins=100)

print('mean: ' + str(np.mean(data)))
print('stdev: ' + str(np.std(data)))
print('25 quant: ' + str(np.quantile(data, q=0.25)))
```

and this code will produce output

```
2.2648170794039064 0.27483818362623197
mean: 10.004894583868193
stdev: 2.800800034575102
25 quant: 8.00859590230189
```

and histogram

[image]